# Python Modbus How to access multiple slave data

Tags: python, modbus, slave

I would like to ask your masters for help.

We communicate with equipment with modbus, but only if the master and slave are 1:1 for the pymodbs.

The problem is that one master wants to manage several slaves.
To do so, we have to use slave_id, which is impossible in the pymodbs, and we found that umodbus is possible.

```
def get_serial_port():
    """ Return serial.Serial instance, ready to use for RS485."""
    port = Serial(port='/dev/ttyS1', baudrate=9600, parity=PARITY_NONE,
              stopbits=1, bytesize=8, timeout=1)

    fh = port.fileno()

    # A struct with configuration for serial port.
    serial_rs485 = struct.pack('hhhhhhhh', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    fcntl.ioctl(fh, 0x542F, serial_rs485)

    return port

serial_port = get_serial_port()
```

ERROR MESSAGE

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 8, in get_serial_port
OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

The problem is that the error is occurring at 0x542F in the process of acquiring the port from umodbus.
How can we solve the problem?

And is it possible to communicate in the pymodbus at 1:m?

[enter link description here](https://umodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/rtu.html)

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: With pymodbus the `unit` parameter specifies the slaveid (see [this exampe](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/dev/source/example/synchronous_client.html)). "the error is occurring" - please include full details of the error occurring in your question (this `ioctl` call may not be needed/supported on your hardware).

Comment: ERROR MESSAGE

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "<stdin>", line 8, in get_serial_port 
    OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device

Comment: So, as suggested in my previous comment, the driver for `/dev/ttyS1` does not support this command. Its difficult to comment further as you have not provided any info on your hardware but there is a good chance it will work without this `ioctl` call (which enables RS485 mode).